# HTML/CSS Orbital Animation with Links Not Working

Tags: html, css, animation, hyperlink

I've looked over my code a thousand times, but I still can't figure out how to allow clicking on animated objects (such as a link to another page). The animations work perfectly, but when I try to click on the links, they don't work properly. I know there is an issue with the placement of the objects on the page, but I can't figure out how to animate them as well, so the link follows the animation. Is there a way I can do this with only HTML and CSS? If I have to use another language, Java or Perl is preferred.

Thanks for the help!

Here is my relevant html and css: (didn't include much styling, just basics)

```css
.orbit-container {
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-top: -275px;
    margin-left: -275px;

    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dotted;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
    -webkit-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
          animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
    
}
.orbit-text-container {
 position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    width: 550px;
    height: 550px;
    margin-top: -275px;
    margin-left: -275px;

 -webkit-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
          animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes orbit {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit-text {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
            transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes orbit-text {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
            transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.orbit-text {
 -webkit-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
       -o-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
          animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
}
.circle-large-center {
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-top: -190px;
 margin-left: -190px;
}
.circle-small-top {
 position: relative;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -60px;
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-top {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: -245px;
}
.circle-small-bottom {
 position: relative;
 top: 90%;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -60px;
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-bottom {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-top: 490px;
}
.circle-small-left {
 position: relative;
 top: 31%;
 left: 100%;
 margin-left: -60px;
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-left {
 top: 0;
 left: 20%;
 margin-top: -330px;
 margin-left: 330px;
}
.circle-small-right {
 position: relative;
 top: 20%;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: -60px;
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-right {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin-left: -550px;
 margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-center {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 20%;
 margin-left: 130px;
 margin-top: 230px;
}
.circle-button-large {
 position: absolute;
 box-shadow: 2px 4px 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 background-color: #F5FAFA;
 border-radius: 50%;
 height: 380px;
 width: 380px;
 opacity: 0.9;
}
.back-image {
 background-color: #3383B8;
 color: #F5FAFA;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
}
.text-medium-large {
 font-size: 30px;
}
.text-center {
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px;
 top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 </head>
<div class="container-fluid back-image screen">
  <div class="circle-button-large circle-large-center"></div>
    <div class="orbit-text-container">
     <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-top orbit-text"><a href="text1.html">Text1</a></div>
     <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-bottom orbit-text"><a href="text2.html">Text2</a></div>
     <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-left orbit-text"><a href="text3.html">Text3</a></div>
     <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-right orbit-text"><a href="text4.html">Text4</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

EDIT: (Nov. 5, 2015):

Here is my JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/hkht1txy/

Comment: Clicking works fine for me.

Comment: You could pause the animation on hover like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hkht1txy/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Danield ! That works great.

Comment: @CalebR - Since the solution worked for you, I added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pause the animation on hover using the `animation-play-state` property.

```
.orbit-text-container:hover, .orbit-text-container:hover .orbit-text {
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
    -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
    -o-animation-play-state: paused;
     animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hkht1txy/1/)

```css
.orbit-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: -275px;
  margin-left: -275px;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
}
.orbit-text-container:hover,
.orbit-text-container:hover .orbit-text {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.orbit-text-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 550px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: -275px;
  margin-left: -275px;
  -webkit-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
  animation: orbit 20s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes orbit {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit-text {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes orbit-text {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-360deg);
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
  }
}
.orbit-text {
  -webkit-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
  -ms-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
  animation: orbit-text 20s linear infinite;
}
.circle-large-center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -190px;
  margin-left: -190px;
}
.circle-small-top {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-top {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: -245px;
}
.circle-small-bottom {
  position: relative;
  top: 90%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-bottom {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 490px;
}
.circle-small-left {
  position: relative;
  top: 31%;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-left {
  top: 0;
  left: 20%;
  margin-top: -330px;
  margin-left: 330px;
}
.circle-small-right {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-right {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -550px;
  margin-top: -60px;
}
.circle-text-center {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 130px;
  margin-top: 230px;
}
.circle-button-large {
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #F5FAFA;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 380px;
  width: 380px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.back-image {
  background-color: #3383B8;
  color: #F5FAFA;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.text-medium-large {
  font-size: 30px;
}
.text-center {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid back-image screen">
  <div class="circle-button-large circle-large-center"></div>
  <div class="orbit-text-container">
    <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-top orbit-text"><a href="text1.html">Text1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-bottom orbit-text"><a href="text2.html">Text2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-left orbit-text"><a href="text3.html">Text3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="text-center text-medium-large circle-text-right orbit-text"><a href="text4.html">Text4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```